# How to represent an array of longs as a query parameter in Swagger 2.0?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I am having a hard time figuring out what would be the correct Swagger 2.0 spec for the case where I am expecting a parameter in the query to be a list of `long` (C#). This is what I tried based on seeing examples where the parameter being passed in query is simple datatypes like `int` or `boolean`. But this does not seem to work. It does not look like it is getting parsed correctly.

My URI is somethng like this : 
https://.../testinstance/FeatureTexts?api-version=2016-09-13&featureIds=1629988727&featureIds=1924980024

And in my API-level test it does not gets resolved to anything similar after the part *api-version=2016-09-13&featureIds=*

```
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "FeatureText"
        ],
        "operationId": "RenderFeatureTexts",
        "description": "The operation to get feature texts for specified features",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "featureIds",
            "in": "query",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "collectionFormat": "multi",
                "items": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "format": "int64"
                }
              },
.......
```

C# code generated by Swagger Codegen:

```csharp
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object> ListFeatureTextsAsync(this IAgentClient operations, object featureIds, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(System.Threading.CancellationToken))
{
    using (var _result = await operations.ListFeatureTextsWithHttpMessagesAsync(featureIds, null, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        return _result.Body;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the parameter definition as shown below, that is, move `type`, `items` and `collectionFormat` out of `schema`. In OpenAPI 2.0, `schema` is only used for body parameters, and other parameter types use `type` etc. directly.

```
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "featureIds",
        "in": "query",
        "required": true,
        "type": "array",
        "collectionFormat": "multi",
        "items": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int64"
        }
```

You can easily catch syntax errors like this by pasting your spec into [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io).

Comment: Thanks for your help. But still running into an error :
 *Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long?' and 'string'* . Error on the generated code.